# Ruby on Rails : display the data stored in my Users table (terminal)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I've searched a lot but cannot find an answer.

How can I see/inspect/display the data stored in my *users* table?

I've seen there is a software for this, [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), but is there a good terminal way to achieve this ?

I've done:

```
rails c
User.all
```

which returns

```
(0.4ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)   User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User >]>
```

So I guess that there is one row here, but how can I view the data (columns & rows) ?

Thanks

Comment: You can try “p User.all” or “User.all.each {|u| p u}”

Answer (score 0):

try this in terminal with - `rails c`:

```
User.pluck().sort().insert(0, ContactUs.column_names).map {|s| s.join "\t|\t" }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `rails db` in terminal it gives access to `sqlite>`

You can start db queries : sqlite> `select * from Users;` 
This should return whatever is stored in the table e.g.

```
1|2020-02-14 13:36:12.604676|2020-02-14 13:36:12.604676|user1|password1

2|2020-02-17 10:27:10.374015|2020-02-17 10:27:10.374015|user2|password2
```

In `rails c`, you could do:

```
pp User.pluck()
```

should return something like

```
  (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
[[1,
  Fri, 14 Feb 2020 13:36:12 UTC +00:00,
  Fri, 14 Feb 2020 13:36:12 UTC +00:00,
  "user1",
  "password1"],
 [2,
  Mon, 17 Feb 2020 10:27:10 UTC +00:00,
  Mon, 17 Feb 2020 10:27:10 UTC +00:00,
  "user2",
  "password2"],
```

or do

```
pp User.all
```

should return something like

```
[#<User:0x000055966dc210b0
  id: 1,
  created_at: Fri, 14 Feb 2020 13:36:12 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Fri, 14 Feb 2020 13:36:12 UTC +00:00,
  username: "user1",
  password_digest: "password1">,
 #<User:0x000055966dc20f20
  id: 2,
  created_at: Mon, 17 Feb 2020 10:27:10 UTC +00:00,
  updated_at: Mon, 17 Feb 2020 10:27:10 UTC +00:00,
  username: "user2",
  password_digest: "password2">,
```

Hope it helps.